# Error 403 when submitting constructed form in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'd like to construct and send a form when a button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-follow', function () {
  let _self = this;
  let token = $('.token').val();
  let username =$('.username').text();
  let form = `<form  method="post">
      <input name="token" value="${token}">
      <input name="flwd" value="${username}">      
    </form>
  `
  console.log('form to submit is:', form);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/follow",
    type: 'post',
    data: form,
    success: function (res) {
      console.log('followed successfully', res)
    },
    error: console.log('an error occured')
  });
});
```

And the constructed form is logged as:

```
form to submit is: <form  method="post">
      <input name="token" value="bjT2rjk6dfefCWQ68Y31VwS8K2DHl8jYjK">
      <input name="followed" value="Bob">      
    </form>
```

However I get `403` error in response, despite the fact that the backend is presumably set up correctly to deal with such POST requests.

What could be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: A 403 error means the server is telling you it understands your request, but it's not allowing you to retrieve the response, for some reason. Without knowing the logic of the endpoint you're calling we can't tell you why that is. Most likely there's some business logic in place which you don't meet the requirements of.

Comment: Also, it's very odd that you're building a `form` in a HTML string and sending that as the data in the request. Are you sure you shouldn't be sending the actual `token` and `followed` values instead?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the route is correct and I am pretty sure of the back-end, but the request does not reach the controller. The middle-ware which enforces user being authenticated avoids it. So there should be a problem in the request. I've never constructed a form before, so I guess the problem lies there.

Comment: If you have middleware to authenticate requests then that will be an issue as well, because you're sending no auth data. Normally this would be included in the request as an API key in the request body, or a bearer token in the header. Again, without knowing the backend requirements, we can't help you

Comment: My guess is that /follow is a directory, and directory listing is forbidden or it needs an authentication to access it

Comment: Well I suppose the auth data is in the token.

Comment: @FlashThunder no, `/follow` is a router endpoint in a MVC framework.

Comment: @Babr what happens when you access it manually from the browser?

Comment: So you need to send the data in the request correctly. Read the API docs for the `data` property of `$.ajax`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in my similar ajax post request the form was in the html and I just captured that using jQuery and serialized it. But in this case when I tried `form.serialize()` I got an error, so appealed to sending the raw data. No idea how to rectify this.

Comment: you can't serialize `form` string, you need to convert it to jQuery object -> use `$(form).serialize()`

Comment: Format your request like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xb79ks6j/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is much cleaner than constructing a form. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/follow",
    type: 'post',
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function (res) {
      console.log('followed successfully', res)
    },
    error: console.log('an error occured')
  });
```

Comment: Works great! Actually I previously tried `form.serialize()` and got error.

Comment: Yes, because `form` is a string, you need to convert it to `jQuery` object with `$` before serializing.